# checking android app memory files

Tags: android, memory, storage

I'm working on an android app, and the app saves data into the memory.
Is there anyway for me to view the files saved through my pc? it would help a lot with debugging. 
Thank you.

Comment: How did you create the files? Is this on device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the device to the PC through a USB connection you can browse the files as you would with a normal folder. Your application files would be found in the /data folder.